# Swagger generated client code not able to call a https localhost endpoint

Tags: java, certificate, swagger

I have a pretty brittle and complicated development setup. I have a ssh tunnel to a machine that exposes a machine on that network, when ssh tunnel is in place, I can access my api easily via `Postman` or `curl` like this.

> curl -X GET -u admin:admin123 -k "https://172.23.1.175/api/storage/aggregates/?fields=space&return_records=true&return_timeout=15" -H "accept: application/hal+json"

My client code is created via `swagger`, for development purpose I want to be able to try within my java application in IntelliJ to make the actual API call. I know this is completely frowned up on. The error I get is this:

```
io.swagger.ontap.client.ApiException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname localhost not verified:
    certificate: sha1/o6KF0+STnresD1HaPMVoHNMgwpY=
    DN: C=US, CN=ontapcloud-net0ejmuaf-1
    subjectAltNames: []
```

This is a newer error after I tried to import the cert to my java config, before it was like this.

> cause javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Can the code below be modified to accommodate so the request will pass through?

```
private void applySslSettings() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = null;
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = null;
        System.out.println("verifyingSsl: " + verifyingSsl);
        if (!verifyingSsl) {
            TrustManager trustAll = new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
            };
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{ trustAll };
            hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }
            };
        } else if (sslCaCert != null) {
            char[] password = null; // Any password will work.
            CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Collection<? extends Certificate> certificates = certificateFactory.generateCertificates(sslCaCert);
            if (certificates.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected non-empty set of trusted certificates");
            }
            KeyStore caKeyStore = newEmptyKeyStore(password);
            int index = 0;
            for (Certificate certificate : certificates) {
                String certificateAlias = "ca" + Integer.toString(index++);
                caKeyStore.setCertificateEntry(certificateAlias, certificate);
            }
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(caKeyStore);
            trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        }

        if (keyManagers != null || trustManagers != null) {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
            httpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        } else {
            httpClient.setSslSocketFactory(null);
        }
        httpClient.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was rather simple, there is attribute that swagger offers that took care of my issue.

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
    apiClient.setBasePath("https://localhost:8077/api");
    apiClient.setVerifyingSsl(false);
```